# How can I pull a Wordpress header and footer into Laravel views?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, header, footer

Before I get to the question, let me say that I saw a similar question here with a fairly detailed response:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115211/loading-wordpress-stuff-on-laravel-site

And it was the closest thing I have found on the web to what I'm looking for, but the potential solution looked like it might end up being so laborious as to not be worth the time.  Here is my situation:

I develop and maintain a small custom SaaS program that typically functions on a subdomain of a client site (say, software.client.com).  The latest version of the code was rewritten using Laravel and there were a lot of gains associated with that.  In the past, when the program was basically procedural spaghetti, if we had a client with a Wordpress site on their primary domain, we ran some atrocious (by best-practices standards) hack-around code to pull the Wordpress header and footer onto the pages of my program - sitting, of course, outside the CMS - while modifying meta tags and doing a number of other things.  It wasn't pretty but it worked.

Now I'm in a situation where I'd like to solve the same problem - that is, to *at least* pull the Wordpress headers and footers onto some of the Laravel subdomain views - but nothing I have found on the web so far has enabled me to make much progress in that direction.  I have found a lot of tutorials explaining how to integrate Laravel and Wordpress, or use one for frontend and the other for backend, etc., but nothing yet about the specific type of integration I'm talking about.

What I have tried so far is implementing some of the code I've used elsewhere into various parts of the Laravel codebase. Most of the recent experiments have been in public/index.php and in Controller methods.  Laravel will allow me to get as far as including the Wordpress config, but if I attempt to go any further I cause a 500 error.  Here's an example snippet that actually attempts to do more than I need, but I can't even get past wp_init().  Imagine the following code in a Laravel Controller method.  The first two lines are OK, but:

```
public function index() {
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
  require '/path_to/wp-config.php';
  $wp->init();                       // from here on, 500 errors occur
  $wp->parse_request();
  $wp->query_posts();
  $wp->register_globals();

  // And then, at some point, I would call and modify get_header()
```

(I didn't really expect this to work from the Controller, but it doesn't work from anywhere else in the codebase I've tried either.)  This is not a situation where I want to hand off control from Laravel to Wordpress for these URLs (I need Laravel functions / DB queries and more flexibility, and I know I could just do that hand-off through public/index.php and routes.php if it would solve the problem).  And for these intallations, I don't need to grab posts or other items from Wordpress.  I would just like to find a way to pull the *header* and *footer* into these views directly from Wordpress while maintaining control of the views in Laravel.  If I can't, among other things, the design team will end up rebuilding headers and footers for every program install on a Wordpress client (for the time being) and they will have to make changes in at least two places when things are modified or updated.

If we have to, we will find a way to live with that until the next program version rollout, but if I can build a solution in what my superiors will deem a reasonable amount of time, we would all be happier.  I hope that I have just missed something simple somewhere and I will be embarrassed to find out that I could have solved this in less time than it took to explain the problem. Thank you for any and all helpful responses and potential solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to cleanly merge the two codebases together. That would cause a disaster.

The complexity of the solution depends on the complexity the information you need to share. The simplest solution possible would be to write something custom to WordPress that builds a document with no body data and just supplies a token, like `{!! $body !!}`. Then, in Laravel, you can do an HTTP request to localhost to fetch this tokenized content. Store the result in a memory cache and use Blade to render the final view.

Essentially, my suggestion boils down to: Create a Blade layout with WordPress.

There's a thousand different ways to do this, and all of them are wrong.